# Equal of xsi:type in JSON Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

How can I hint the type of embedded objects in [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html), analogous to `xsi:type` in XML Schema?

**Example** schema document:

```
{
    "type": "storeRequest",
    "properties": {
        "txid": {
            "description": "Transaction ID to prevent double committing",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "objects": {
            "description": "Objects to store",
            "type": "array"
            "items": {
                "type": "object"
            },
            "minItems": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true
        },
    },
    "required": ["txid", "objects"]
}
```

This is a request the client sends to the server to store multiple objects in the database. Now how can I recursively validate the content of **objects** when it can contain more than one type of object. (Plymorphism, really).

Comment: I'd recommend you to use the OpenAPI support to polymorphism. I've written about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38626716/json-and-object-inheritance/46839490#46839490

Comment: @dbaltor Thanks for the good advice. How much support does this feature have in the different generated client/server stubs?

Comment: Hi @vbence, haven't tried yet but it seems to support only client stubs as per this comment from the author: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5120#issuecomment-588846548

Answer (score 1):

There is not an equivalent to `xsi:type` in `JSON-schema` AFAIK.
Perhaps the most `JSON-schema` idiomatic way to hint the existence of types would be the explicit definition of types as schemas and referencing them through `$ref`:

```
{
    "properties" : {
        "wheels" : {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : "$ref" : "#/definitions/wheel"
        }
    }

    "definitions" : {
        "wheel" : {
            "type" : "object"
        }
    }
}
```

Another way could be to give a hint through enums :

```
    {
    "definitions" : {
        "vehicle" : {
            "properties" : {
                "type" : {
                    "enum" : ["car", "bike", "plane"]
                }
            }
        },
        "plane" : {
            "properties" : {
                "type" : {
                    "enum" : "plane"
                }
            }
            "allOf" : ["$ref" : "#/definitions/vehicle"]
        }
     }
   }
```

Finally you can also add whatever tag you can process to a `JSON-schema` and follow your conventions.

Be aware that you are not going to find an equivalent translation between typical object oriented programming languages (`java`, `C#`) inheritance semantics and `JSON-schema`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. What I was hoping for is some way to inject type information into the document which is being inspected.

Comment: I added an example to the question.

Comment: I would just an anyOf list of valid schemas for your objects, and use an enum to indicate in each actual object which schema it validates.