# JSON and object inheritance

Tags: rest, object, inheritance

We are trying to move from SOAP to REST and we stumbled across this issue
Here party can be of type Individual or Organization.

Sample XMLs

```
<customer>
  <details>
    <party xsi:type="Individual">
      <externalID>ABC123</externalID>
      <firstname>John</firstname>
      <lastname>Smith</lastname>
    </party>
  </details>
</customer>

<customer>
  <details>
    <party xsi:type="Organization">
      <externalID>APPLE</externalID>
      <organizationName>Apple Inc</organizationName>
      <listingName>APPLE</listingName>
    </party>
  </details>
</customer>
```

However when we move to JSON representation of the same, we encounter the problem where the inheritance information is lost

JSON Sample

```
{
  "customer": {
    "details": {
      "party": {
        "externalID": "ABC123",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "customer": {
    "details": {
      "party": {
        "externalID": "APPLE",
        "organizationName": "Apple Inc",
        "listingName": "APPLE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when we convert the JSON back to Java object using libraries like Gson, we loose the definition of Individual or Organization.

While one of the workaround is to build additional services to retrieve the "details" returning the concrete types (Individual or Organization), 
is there any other approach to handle this in JSON?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question.  I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627344/equal-of-xsitype-in-json-schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom Gson deserializer and based on existence of organisationName field you create instance of either Organization or Individual class in this deserializar. Something like what is specified here: [Gson - deserialization to specific object type based on field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21767485/gson-deserialization-to-specific-object-type-based-on-field-value), instead of "type" you can check for the existence of your property.

Answer (score 3):

It's been possible to combine schemas using keywords such as oneOf, allOf, anyOf and get the payload validated since JSON schema v1.0.

https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html

However, composition has been enhanced by the keyword **discriminator** incorporated on OpenAPI (former Swagger) to barely support polymorphism. In OpenAPI 3.0, this support has been enhanced by the addition of **oneOf** keyword.

Your inheritance could be modeled using a combination of oneOf (for choosing one of the children) and allOf (for combining parent and child).

```
paths:
  /customers:
  post:
   requestBody:
    content:
      application/json:
        schema:
          oneOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Individual
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Organization
          discriminator:
            propertyName: customer_type
   responses:
     '201':
       description: Created
components:
  schemas:
    Customer:
      type: object
      required:
        - customer_type
        - externalID
      properties:
        customer_type:
          type: string
        externalID:
          type: integer
      discriminator:
        property_name: customer_type
    Individual:
      allOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Customer"
        - type: object
        - properties:
          firtName
            type: string
          lastName
            type: string
    Organisation:
      allOf:
        - $ref: "#/components/schemas/Customer"
        - type: object
        - properties:
          organisationName
            type: string
          listingName
            type: string
```

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.0.md#schemaComposition

**18/02/2020 Edit:**
For generating Java code using Jackson, [OpenAPITools](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator) has seemingly been fixed by the [PR #5120](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/5120)

Comment: It's true that OAS allows this.  However, there is no support for the feature to be displayed in Swagger UI ([link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2438)), and I think a feature is of limited use if you can't show it to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I found a resource submitted by IBM and felt it may be of some help. It's linked below.

On pg. 27 they convert:

```
<year xsi:type="xs:positiveInteger">1989</year>
```

To:

```
{ "xsi:type" : "xs:positiveInteger", value : 1989 }
```

Thus, I think your code should convert to:

```
{
  "customer": {
    "details": {
      "party": {
        "xsi:type": "Individual",
        "externalID": "ABC123",
        "firstname": "John",
        "lastname": "Smith"
      }
    }
  }
}

{
  "customer": {
    "details": {
      "party": {
        "xsi:type": "Organization",
        "externalID": "APPLE",
        "organizationName": "Apple Inc",
        "listingName": "APPLE"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Resource for reference: https://www.w3.org/2011/10/integration-workshop/s/ExperienceswithJSONandXMLTransformations.v08.pdf